# Your Meetup may be over, but you can continue to be involved in your New York community

Tags: bug, meetups

The follow-up email I got from meetup.com said New York, but I'm not in New York. Not sure if that's a meetup bug or an error on SO's side

Comment: nothing y'all can do about it now, just figured i'd let y'all know

Comment: I reached out to a contact from Meetup.com, but haven't heard back about the specific cause of that error. Anyway, I apologize for that and will do what I can to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 3):

That was an automated email that Meetup sent to everyone (I think). I'm not sure why it specified a location if it wasn't going to use the location of the event you RSVP'd to. I'll look into it, but it was a meetup bug, not an SO one. Thanks for the heads up.